# Lost the Modern UI Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I accidentally removed the Modern UI IE Icon. Is there any way to get it back?

I'm able to run the normal Internet Explorer, but not the Modern UI one, please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This also happened to me.

After trying lots of things, i found out IE needs to be the default browser or else immersive IE won't work/exist. That's a little odd, i hope it gets fixed in some update.

Answer (score 5):

When on the Modern UI interface, hit the I key, this will bring up all the apps starting with I, right click on the IE tile, this will put a check by it, then go down to the right lower corner and click "Pin"

You may have to drag the IE tile to where you want it when you go back to the main Modern UI screen.

If you want to see all the apps availabe while in the I section (or any other app search section), hit esc key.

Not sure how to do it on a touch screen.

.

[image]

.
Or you can try Control Panel > (icon view) > Recovery . Refresh

.
[image]

Comment: It would seem that someone uninstalled it on my computer, since I get an IE icon, but it's not the metro one. :(

Comment: Try Control Panel (icon view) > Recovery, try Reset option

Comment: I'll try a restore when I get some time. Reset is kinda scary. I'm worried if it would delete my Libraries content.

Comment: check my edit to my post, use the Refresh option in control panel.